# prompt a user to enter a key in a dictionary to output its value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to figure out ways to get the users input of a specify key in order to output its corresponding value. Thing is I'm not too sure if I set up my dictionary correctly. I have to define a dictionary with an attached text file and in that text file each line has a country name, a space, and income which looks similar to something like this - "Qatar $129,700".

My thing is, how do I get it to where I can type in the countries name and have it output it's correct income value?

Current code:

```
import string
import re
import fileinput


infile = open("C:\\Users\\mrbal\\Desktop\\Homework 
Assignments\\percapita.txt", "r")

dict1 = {}
for line in infile:
    x = line.split(" ")
    countryName = x[0]
    income = x[1]
    print(countryName, income)

print("##############################")

#country = input("Please enter the desired country: ")
```

First, did I set up the dictionary correctly?

Second, in this current setup, when I run the program it outputs the contents of my file which is good, but I still need the user to input a country from the dictionary and then have it output its value. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can improve in your code:

1. You are not initializing the dict with values, do it.
2. You can use PEP compliant variable names like `country_name` instead of `countryName`
3. You open the file but don't close it. Use `with` to avoid this.

So, the code becomes:

```
import string
import re
import fileinput


with open("C:\\Users\\mrbal\\Desktop\\Homework Assignments\\percapita.txt", "r") as infile:

    incomes = {}
    for line in infile:
        x = line.split(" ")
        country_name, income = x[0], x[1]
        print(country_name, income)
        incomes[country_name] = income

print("##############################")

country = input("Please enter the desired country: ")
print(incomes.get(country, "No information found for country %s" % country))
```

If you would like to give list of country to the user, just add an additional print statement:

```
print("Options for country are: %s" % incomes.keys())
```

Comment: I believe that you need the `incomes` assignment inside the loop.  You want *all* of the file data, not merely the last one.

Comment: @Prune Thanks for pointing, incorrect indentation on my part :|

Comment: When I run your version of the code I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)." What does that mean?  Is this due to not unpacking the items in the dictionary into variables?

Comment: @CoDyDaTallGuy That error will occur when your CSV file has more than 2 columns in it, since I assume that there are always 2. Can you check that the format of the CSV is correct, and that ` ` is the delimiter? In the meantime, I've altered the code to unpack into a variable.

Comment: @mu The format is correct, but I just noticed that on line 12 you're using the "countryName" variable when I believe it should be "country_name". Changing that has cleared up all the errors and the program now works as intended.

Comment: @CoDyDaTallGuy Corrected. If that helped, don't forget to accept the answer :)